# Children spacing not working when reversed order has breakpoint in Tailwind

Tags: flexbox, tailwind-css, postcss, tailwind-in-js

I have a landing page that alternates between image and text blocks using `flex-row` and `flex-row-reverse`:

[image]

I can achieve this pretty simply in react by flipping the order as I map over my list without having to alter the order of the divs:

```js
idx % 2 === 0 ? 'flex-row-reverse space-x-reverse' : 'flex-row'
```

The problem arose when I realized on mobile I want them to stack like so:

[image]

I mocked up what's happening in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-example-forked-py9yk?file=/index.html:222-714) like so:

```html
<div
  class="flex items-center flex-col mb-10 sm:flex-row sm:space-x-10"
>
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-red-500">first</div>
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-blue-600">second</div>
</div>
<div
  class="flex items-center flex-col mb-10 sm:flex-row-reverse space-x-reverse sm:space-x-10"
>
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-red-500">first</div>
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-blue-600">second</div>
</div>
```

The mobile version looks as expected but the larger breakpoints looks as if `space-x-reverse` is getting recognized:

[image]

Any idea how to have the reversed row recognize `space-x-reverse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `sm:` prefix on `space-x-reverse`.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="flex items-center flex-col mb-10 sm:flex-row sm:space-x-10">
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-red-500">first</div>
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-blue-600">second</div>
</div>
<div class="flex items-center flex-col mb-10 sm:flex-row-reverse sm:space-x-reverse sm:space-x-10">
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-red-500">first</div>
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-blue-600">second</div>
</div>
```